# Power Bi: Get Column Name with Maximum and Minimum other column value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a sheet containing employees leave data-

```
Staff Leave Taken   Month
A       19         April
A        3         May
A        3         June
B        2         April
B        1         May
B        0         June
C        0         April
C        0         May
C        1         June
```

I want to calculate the Employee whose has taken maximum no. of leaves and name of employee whose has taken minimum no. of leaves. 
Here Employee with max. leaves is A and with min. is C.
I am having trouble in getting the maximum no. of leaves.

```
X = MAX( SUMX ( SUMMARIZE ( Table1, Table1[STAFF], Table1[Leaves] ), [Leaves] ))
```

But it is showing some error.

I tried to group by staff name then also it is not working out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first create a summary table with the following DAX:

```
Summary = SUMMARIZE(Table1, Table1[Staff], "Leaves", SUM(Table1[Leave Taken]))
```

[image: summary]

Then you can use the following DAX measure to get the Max / Min name:

```
Max Name = 
CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('Summary'[Staff], 1),
    FILTER(
        Summary,
        Summary[Leaves] = MAX(Summary[Leaves])
    )
)
```

-

```
Min Name = 
CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('Summary'[Staff], 1),
    FILTER(
        Summary,
        Summary[Leaves] = MIN(Summary[Leaves])
    )
)
```

[image: result]

Comment: But how can I make this data's relationship with month? Like who's is having max. Or min leaves in april or may or june.